# Argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable when trying to update a model object

Tags: django

Getting error `Argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable` and can't figure out why.

It happens at the line  `if model_form.is_valid():`

Views.py

```
def update_model(request, pricemodel_id):
    """ Update a part given its id. """
    pricemod = Part.objects.get(id=pricemodel_id)
    if request.method == "POST":
        print "post request"
        model_form = priceform(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=pricemod)
        model_form.is_update = True
        if request.user == pricemod.adder:
            #from ipdb import set_trace; set_trace()
            if model_form.is_valid():
```

Forms.py

```
class priceform(ModelForm):
# price Form: form associated to the Part model
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(priceform, self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
        self.is_update=False
        choices = UniPart.objects.all().values('manufacturer').distinct()
    def clean(self):
        if self.cleaned_data and 'modelname' not in self.cleaned_data:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Some error message")
            if not self.is_update:
                return self.cleaned_data
            return self.cleaned_data
    class Meta:
        model = Part
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like it is because wrong indention in your clean method. Current it doesn't return anything, i.e it returns `None`, but must return the `self.cleaned_data`. All of your `clean` method code is under `if`, which will raise an exception. And if this `if` is not matched, None is returned.

Try this:

```
class priceform(ModelForm):
    # ...
    def clean(self):
        if self.cleaned_data and 'modelname' not in self.cleaned_data:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Some error message")
        if not self.is_update:
            return self.cleaned_data
        return self.cleaned_data

    # ...
```

Comment: Thanks could you really briefly explain what is the clean method doing and how does the is_valid method know to check it?

Comment: `is_valid` calls chain of methods, that performs validation. The last part: `clean_<fieldname>` methods are called for each field, then `clean` method. `clean_<fieldname>` method validates data exclusively for `<fieldname>` field. In `clean`, `self.cleaned_data` contains data, already validated by corresponding `clean_<fieldname>` methods. So here can be validated some general rules, and rules related to two or more linked fields, when for ex. one field must take into account another field. Here is [detailed doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/)